# Widget is equal to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, nonetype

I'm making a GUI using Tkinter which allows data to be entered in one of the windows:

```
enterscore = Entry(window4, font="Helvatica 25", textvariable = newscore).pack()
```

I am trying to make a button which will save the entered data as a variable:

```
savebttn = Button(window4, text= "Save", width=5, height=2, font="Helvatica 25", command = savescore).pack()
```

Where:

```
def savescore():
    score = enterscore.get()
```

However, if I run the program it returns the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it was a duplicate as I didn't understand what the problem was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
enterscore = Entry(window4, font="Helvatica 25", textvariable = newscore).pack()
```

Calling `pack` returns `None`, not the widget. `tkinter` does not support that sort of method chaining. Instead do:

```
enterscore = Entry(window4, font="Helvatica 25", textvariable = newscore)
enterscore.pack()
```

This constructs the widget, and sets `enterscore` to point at it. Calling `enterscore.pack` then has the same effect as above, but `eneterscore` is left pointing at the correct object (the widget, not `None`)

Answer (score 1):

`pack` method returns `None`. You need to separate the statement that create the `Entry` and the statemetn that pack.

```
enterscore = Entry(window4, font="Helvatica 25", textvariable=newscore)
enterscore.pack()
```

Same for the `savebttn`.